# Redirecting G Suite mail to the users' secondary emails

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

We as a small company have a G Suite Edu account. 
Our emails are handled somewhere else, but we would like each user's email in the domain forwarded to their personal (secondary email). That's because we have personal email accounts not ending with @ourdomain.xyz, meaning that any email going to their G Suite email gets lost, because there are no email addresses existing that would catch those mails. How is this possible to achieve?

Thanks

Comment: related doc can be found here https://support.google.com/a/answer/175745?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified the number of users but as you mention "small company" the 2 approaches I describe below are primarily geared for a small number of users and not a complete domain wide rewriting of the email address domain.

**The user controlled approach:** Each user from the GMail Web UI sets a forwarding account.

1. Click the gear icon in the top right of the GMail window|Settings|Forwarding and POP/IMAP
2. Click the "Add a forwarding address"
3. The user can then add the email address they wish their emails to be forwared to.
4. click the save changes button at the bottom of the page.

**The Administrator approach:** Using GSuite Administrator *(for Business, I'm assuming it's the same options are available for Edu.)*

1. Goto Apps>G Suite>Settings for Gmail>Advanced settings (or search for routing in the search box).
2. Located the "Recipient Address Map"
3. Hover over it and select edit
4. There are various options here but you can enter an email address mapping to forward emails to for recipient addresses. You can also have them delivered to the GMail account if you wish.

This obviously requires a lot more work and co-ordination for the administrator to ensure the target addresses are maintained up to date.

For domain wide address rewriting there are Inbound and Internal-receiving routing rules you can configure in this section where you have domain wide readdressing capability.